# Excel formula, calculate product of values in each column of dynamic array

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I'm working on a formula for a "result" column in a table that looks up data in another table based on some criteria in the main one, then displays it.  Of the point where I'm getting stumped at, it is returning a dynamic 2D array (row returns are variable dependent on an `FILTER`/`MATCH` lookup).  Example (4 columns x 3 rows) return value: `{1,2,3,4;1,2,3,4;1,2,3,4}`

I want to get the product of the values in each column such that the output from the formula using the example return value above would be this: `{1,8,27,64}`

(Which is the equivalent of doing this: `{1,2,3,4} * {1,2,3,4} * {1,2,3,4}`)

How do I accomplish this using only formula functions?

All of my google searches have been coming back with methods that assume static table size, multiply the columns against each other, and/or the table "existing" within a sheet somewhere (and still don't give the result I'm looking for).

---

I've already figured this out via VBA, but due to the nature of how I'm using the sheet, waiting for the updates to run via VBA are too slow.  It's not that it takes forever - it's only about 3-4 seconds for ~60 rows - but rather that I make a change to my lookup table, wait for the update to the result column in the main table, check the results, make another change, rinse & repeat 50 some odd times while I fine tune things to look the way I want them to, and the delays are wearing on me.

I'm also unsure that I can use helper rows/columns as the results would need to be packed too close together and would just display `#SPILL`, which results in the formulas referencing it just showing the same thing.  So it looks like this needs to be self contained.

Plugins are an absolute no.

---

(Other little edit: Whoops, I put `INDEX`/`MATCH` above when I meant `FILTER`/`MATCH`.)

**EDIT:** Hopefully this will help clarify?

Here's the structure of my main table where this formula resides:
[image]

`My Formula` takes the words from ColA and ColB and uses `FILTER`/`MATCH` to do a lookup that 1) returns multiple results, 2) the return results are entire rows, and 3) is an exact match (it returns nothing for words in ColA and ColB that don't exist in the lookup table).

This means that, as of the current state of the formula, I'm getting 2D arrays back for most of the rows in the main table.  AFAICT, I'm not going to be able to stick these into a helper column somewhere as they'll overlap and just cause `#SPILL` which then won't evaluate in whatever formulas then reference them.

I need to turn these into 1D arrays that are 1 row x same-#-as-source columns where the result in each column is the product of only that column's contents.  I'm then going to continue building off from this formula with more formula to achieve my final result that will fit nicely in the single cell.  (I already have that piece solved.  It's just going from the 2D -> 1D product array I need help with.)

Comment: Post your input then expected output and explain how to achieve that.

Comment: Check out sumproduct().

Comment: Until MS release functions such as `BYROW` and `BYCOL`, there is no shorthand method by which an array of products (by column or row) can be obtained from an `array` (there is such a method when querying a `range`, but that isn't relevant to your case). The only option would be to create a formula which comprises as many arguments as there are columns in the input array and then pass these to `CHOOSE`. If the number of columns to be considered is fixed and small, this might be a feasible option. Otherwise, share a dataset so that alternatives to your `INDEX`/`MATCH` set-up can be sought.

Comment: @Harun24HR, "input" (example) is the posted ```{1,2,3,4;1,2,3,4;1,2,3,4}``` and expected output with that example is the posted ```{1,8,27,64}```.  The input is simply a result of another formula that I want to nest inside of the solution formula.  So, if we want to say ```MyFormula``` represents the input array, then a (mockup) solution would be ```PRODUCT(MyFormula)``` (though this one obviously doesn't work as it multiplies all of the values together).

Comment: @SolarMike, ```SUMPRODUCT()``` does not do what I want.  It multiplies the values in the wrong order and then sums them.

Comment: Updated with further clarification.

Comment: So I gave you an answer based on a question that you failed to state properly, thanks.

Comment: @JosWoolley, reading about ```BYROW```, that sounds like it might be exactly the behavior I want, though it's hard to confirm without being able to use it, yet.  Is there an ETR anywhere for these types of things?

Comment: @SolarMike, my opening line said "I'm working on a formula for a "result" column in a table".  This to me means it's not just one result cell.  I also later mentioned in the original post that I did not believe helper rows/columns would work due to them being packed too closely to each other and causing ```#SPILL```.  I also never said I wanted the products summed.

Comment: @FotS so when you put: {1,8,27,64} (Which is the equivalent of doing this: {1,2,3,4} * {1,2,3,4} * {1,2,3,4}) my example can be expanded to do that, you can edit that though.

Comment: @FotS `BYCOL` and `BYROW` currently available to Office Insiders only - wider release date not known. How many columns will your 2D array comprise? As I said, if this number is fixed and not too large, a solution is possible.

Comment: @JosWoolley, hmm, sorry, maybe ```BYCOL``` is actually it?  This is very confusing to me how ```BYROW``` returns the data as *columns*, but then subsequent functions will operate over the result's *rows*.  Still, going to need to wait and see, but this might be it.  EDIT: Currently 10 columns, but that could change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=LET(z,MyArray,a,INDEX(z,,1),b,INDEX(z,,2),c,INDEX(z,,3),d,INDEX(z,,4),CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},PRODUCT(a),PRODUCT(b),PRODUCT(c),PRODUCT(d)))`

where `MyArray` is the construction which returns your 2D array, e.g.

`{1,2,3,4;1,2,3,4;1,2,3,4}`

The above assumes that `MyArray` returns an array comprising 4 columns. For each additional column beyond that number, an additional *name* and *calculation* parameter will be required within the `LET` function. What's more, the array passed to `CHOOSE` should be adjusted such that it comprises an array of integers from 1 up to the number of columns returned by `MyArray`.

For example, if `MyArray` returned instead:

`{1,2,3,4,5;1,2,3,4,5;1,2,3,4,5}`

the required construction would be:

`=LET(z,MyArray,a,INDEX(z,,1),b,INDEX(z,,2),c,INDEX(z,,3),d,INDEX(z,,4),e,INDEX(z,,5),CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5},PRODUCT(a),PRODUCT(b),PRODUCT(c),PRODUCT(d),PRODUCT(e)))`

***Edit***: better is to replace the static array passed to `CHOOSE` with a `SEQUENCE` construction:

`=LET(z,MyArray,a,INDEX(z,,1),b,INDEX(z,,2),c,INDEX(z,,3),d,INDEX(z,,4),e,INDEX(z,,5),CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(z)),PRODUCT(a),PRODUCT(b),PRODUCT(c),PRODUCT(d),PRODUCT(e)))`

Comment: Thank you, this works.  Not the most elegant solution considering I have 10 columns at the moment and this may change in the future, but until the new ```BYCOL``` function is released, I think this is the best way.  (Which, by the way, I took the time to get a hold of the Insider version for purposes of playing with those new functions, and ```BYCOL(MyArray,LAMBDA(array,PRODUCT(array)))``` (where "array" is literally typed in there) does work.)  Your answer with ```LET```, though, has made me realize that the next steps I need to take have a better solution. XD

Comment: Agreed that it's far from ideal! FYI have added a slighly improved version which replaces the static array passed to `CHOOSE` with a `SEQUENCE` construction.

Answer (score 0):

So:

EDIT based on comment:
If the sumproduct is in the wrong order, then the alternative is simple:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D10:F10,D11:F11,D12:F12,D13:F13)


=sumproduct(A1:A4,B1:B4,C1:C4)
```

Then A1:A4 (and the other arrays) could be the index with match retrieving the data.

Or have the index and match in other cells and use those result in the sumproduct.

Had a play, making up some data as so:

[image]

In Cell D88:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$H$5,MATCH($C10,$A$2:$A$5,0),MATCH(D$9,$B$1:$H$1,0))
```

In cell D15:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D10:D13,E10:E13,F10:F13)
```

In cells D9:F9 is data validation to choose the column heading A:G.

Comment: This does not work.  1) Requires the "input" array to exist somewhere on the sheet (how do I do this for ~60 input arrays that can also potentially shrink or grow if I remove or add lines to the main table?), and 2) ```SUMPRODUCT()``` (to my understanding) multiplies the values row-wise (equivalent of ```{1;1;1} * {2;2;2} * {3;3;3} * {4;4;4}```, not what I want) and then sums them (also not what I want).

Comment: “Wrong order”? A*B*C is the same as B*A*C is the same as A*C*B etc

Comment: @FotS Check the edit, sumproduct works on rows or columns....

Comment: Ok, but it's still summing it.  I don't want the results summed.  I'm also not able to put the array result into a helper column somewhere as then it'll just show ```#SPILL``` and won't evaluate into a formula that references it.

Comment: @FotS well, I would start looking at &

Comment: I already know ```&```.  That doesn't help here either.